# SQL избыточные данные при left join

Tags: php, sql

У меня есть основная таблица и несколько второстепенных. Одной записи из основной таблицы может соответствовать несколько записей из второстепенной. Мне нужно вывести их как единую таблицу, если я просто делаю через left join, то у меня выводится куча избыточной, дублирующей информации, которая мне не нужна.

Например:

```
SELECT * 
FROM in_fileindex_main main
LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly add ON 
    (main.DocumentNumber = add.DocumentNumber)
LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability app ON 
    (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber)
WHERE 1;
```

То выведется что-то типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, add и app таблицы не связаны между собой, они связаны только с основной таблицей main. Можно ли как-то построить запрос, чтобы не было дублирующей информации и вывод был соответственно следующим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `DISTINCT` или просто можно сделать `GROUP BY` по ID (как пример GROUP BY main.id  ). Но оптимальнее сделать `DISTINCT` т.к это сэкономит серверные ресурсы.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM in_fileindex_main main LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly add ON (main.DocumentNumber = add.DocumentNumber) LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability app ON (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber) WHERE 1
```

> UPDATE v.2

```
SELECT DISTINCT main.* FROM in_fileindex_main as main LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_additionaly as add ON (main.DocumentNumber = add.DocumentNumber) LEFT JOIN in_fileindex_applicability as app ON (main.DocumentNumber = app.DocumentNumber) WHERE 1
```

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, но результат не изменился

Comment: @findley вы попробовали обе версии т.е DISTINCT и GROUP BY ? и без изменений?  Точно?  думаю вы что т оне так делаете, в вашем примере вы указываете только * , может у вас это некорректно работает, можно попробовать конкретизировать, дополню ответ попробуйте по второму методу

Comment: @findley кстати, заметил что в вашем примере все таки должно быть чёткое WHERE . вы что то  не досказываете, можете показать  корректную таблицу с полями? по какому параметру другие таблицы должны связываться с таблицой main ?? Медитация нам не поможет :)

Comment: здравствуйте, сейчас попробую вторую версию, по поводу where, если мне надо вывести все, то никакого условия нету, оно появляется, если пользователь будет использовать поиск, group by не пробовал

Comment: попробовал, по второй версии у меня выводятся только данные из таблицы main

Comment: @findley ну вот прекрастно... укажите в SELECT все таблицы (я указал main для примера)   SELECT DISTINCT main.*, add.*, app.*  FROM ...

Comment: Извиняюсь за столь поздний ответ, но при использовании DISTINCT с тремя таблицами не работает, результат тот же самый(

Answer (score 0):

```
    select c.name, m.pay, cp.cnt from Client c
    left join (select clientID, sum(money) as pay from Pays group by clientID) m on c.clientID = m.clientID
    left join (select clientID, count(productID) as cnt from ClientProducts group by clientID) cp on c.clientID = cp.clientID
```

Comment: здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ, но не могли бы вы спроецировать это на мой пример, а то у меня самого что-то не выходит. Если не сложно, конечно

Comment: в вашем запросе все правильно, но возможно влияет WHERE 1, это надо убрать. Также, причиной может быть дублирование информации в исходных таблицах - надо проверить. Еще я бы порекомендовал не использовать системные слова в алиасах (add -> ad, main -> m)

Comment: здравствуйте, where 1 убрал, дублирования информации в самих sql таблицах нету, системные слова убрал. Так называемое "декартово произведение" между всеми тремя таблица так и осталось, а у меня как видно из задания связи между 2 и 3 таблицами вообще нет